# Dynamically modifying tiles in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts, tiles, struts-1

I'm trying to modify how my pages look like, based on which `module` is currently active. So basically, I have one common set of jsp pages, that need to have tiles changed based on the module.

I am able to implement basic tiles independently with each module. This requires me to specify in the jsp the definition of the tile. So my question is, how can I change the definiton, and hence, have the tiles change dynamically based on the module.

I'm using Tiles with Struts 1.1 (Not my choice, but the requirements were such), and am new to this framework.

**Edit**: I've tried going through the docs, browsing other forums and blogs, but havent encountered anything similar to this. Is there any other way to achieve this, probably without switching the tile definitions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: @dave-newton the tile in a JSP page, based on the module. There are two sets of tiles, for one set of JSPs.

Comment: What you mean by module and dynamical changes? Is module a jsp with tiles inside and the another module is different jsp with different set of tiles? Then you can create action that lands on one of them? http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-tiles/examples.html tells how you have an layout to combine x amount of tiles. Cannot you have another layout of y amount of different tiles and some link or whatever to go to and from these two layouts? The idea of tiles is, that you define them once and combine n times to different layout jsp:s by adding the tags to different order in each of the pages.

Comment: By modules I mean this http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-multiple-configuration-files-example/ . Now after I click on a link (for ex), I am able to change from one Module to another (using SwitchAction). Now both modules have their own set of JSP and Tiles. However, since I only require them to look different from one another, I want them to share their JSP, while have their own Tiles. Anything else I can clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is you will be having 2 definition for 1 JSP in tiles-defs.xml file. Like

```
<definition name="outputPage" extends="mainLayout">
    <put name="title" value="HELLO" />
    <put name="body"   value="/pages/Welcome.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="outputPage2" extends="mainLayout">
    <put name="title" value="HELLO2" />
    <put name="body"   value="/pages/tile2.jsp" />
</definition>
```

One way I suggest to achieve your requirement is by setting module type in attribute (say `request.setAttribute("module", "module2");`).

Suppose you will be having 2 forwards for same JSP page in struts-config.xml.

```
    <action
            path="/Welcome"
            forward="/pages/tileTest.jsp"/>  
<action
            path="/customerAction"
            type="xyz.actions.CustomerAction"
            name="customerForm"
            scope="request">

            <forward name="tile" path="/Welcome.do"></forward>
            <forward name="customer" path="/pages/customer.jsp"></forward>
       </action>
```

Then in your JSP page(tileTest.jsp), the tiles will be defined something like

```
    <%@page language="java" pageEncoding="shift-jis"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<logic:notEmpty name="module">
<logic:equal name="module" value="module1">
<tiles:insert definition="outputPage" flush="true" />
</logic:equal>
</logic:notEmpty>

<logic:notEmpty name="module">
<logic:equal name="module" value="module2">
<tiles:insert definition="outputPage2" flush="true" />
</logic:equal>
</logic:notEmpty>

<logic:empty name="module">
<tiles:insert definition="outputPage" flush="true" />
</logic:empty>
```

Comment: Thanks Naved. However, since I have two modules (and subsequently two tiles-def.xml), when I switch from one module to another, I need to supply a `prefix` attribute. Now in the new module's struts-config.xml, all action-mappings are relative to the prefix I supplied, as a result of which, it fetches JSPs from the prefix directory. How can I force it to not append the prefix when switching? Not sure if I explained my question very well. I probably should create a new question for this.

Comment: I am not sure, but if you can check the prefix in the Actions and based on that if you set an attribute for JSP to dynamically load the tiles (as described in the answer), may solve your problem. But I think for that you have to have only one tiles-def.xml

Comment: Well, technically this does dynamically change the tiles, so I'll accept this answer. However, I'm still having some issues in forcing them to refer to the same set of JSPs.